# How can I read the text in the file from remote machine(from IIS6.0 Virtual directory) either using Javascript or Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

how can I read the text in the file from remote machine(from IIS6.0 Virtual directory) either using Javascript or Ajax and copy into client machine 'TEMP/specified' Folder

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700231 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700397 have been asked the last hour??

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var http = false;

if(navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
  http = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
} else {
  http = new XMLHttpRequest();
}

http.open("GET", "test.txt");
http.onreadystatechange=function() {
  if(http.readyState == 4) {
    alert(http.responseText);
  }
}
http.send(null);
</script>
```

P.S. You cannot actually save file to client's machine