# Read a file(.txt/.xml) from remote machine?

Tags: asp.net

how can I read the text in the file(.txt/.xml) from remote machine(from IIS6.0 Virtual directory) either using Ajax and copy into client machine 'TEMP/specified' Folder.

Following steps should happen, On Click upon the button:
1) request should go to the server( it is ASP.NET3.5 application and hosted in IIS6.0)
2) open the file(.txt/.xml) and read the full content then pass to the client machine.
3) Take(read) the content and copied in client machine specified path (it may be TEMP folder or specified Folder).

It would be really great if any sample code is provided for the same

Thanks

Comment: Which is most difficult part in your process?

Comment: This is an almost 100% duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700231 you asked 40 minutes ago.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var http = false;

if(navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
  http = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
} else {
  http = new XMLHttpRequest();
}

http.open("GET", "test.txt");
http.onreadystatechange=function() {
  if(http.readyState == 4) {
    alert(http.responseText);
  }
}
http.send(null);
</script>
```

P.S. You cannot actually save a file to local client's machine